# Simulation of images of a fluorescent bead

Tags: image-processing

Figure 2 in the paper by Thompson et al. "Precise Nanometer Localization Analysis for Individual Fluorescent Probes" (https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/11964263/) presents series of images of a fluorescent bead for different numbers of photons N in the spot. Could someone give me some practical hints how to simulate such images? I see that the resolution of each image is the same and the quality depends on the numbers of photons N. The authors explain that "images with different numbers of photons were created by accumulating, offline, varying numbers of frames from a time-series stack of a single bead" but it is still not clear for me how to proceed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I wrote some simple Matlab code for 1D case based on your advice but probably that  is not exactly what you meant. I have a bit different background and it is difficult to follow yours hints. Could you please write me how to improve my calculations?   x = -10:1:10; A = 1; sigma = 2; gaussian = A*exp(-(x.^2)/(2*sigma^2)); k = 5; nr_frames = 100; p = zeros(size(x));
for frame = 1 : nr_frames; lambda  = gaussian; poisson = (lambda.^k).*exp(-lambda)./factorial(k); p = p + poisson + 0.01*randn(size(x));                                        end; p = p/nr_frames;

Comment: Thank you. I still do not understand one issue. If I add zero mean noise to each image of a particle, then it is clear that taking average over all such images, the quality  will be improve when the number of  images will increase (as the average of noise will go to zero). Is it the general idea behind these simulations?   What kind of noise it is common to consider for simulation of such microscopy images?

Comment: Then, what is your Poisson generator?